# How can add image in UIContextualAction in UITableview DataSource method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**i am trying to add image in the UIContextualAction , see the code below:-**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
   // Write action code for the Flag
    let FlagAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "View", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)
    })
    FlagAction.image =  UIImage(named: "flag")
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [FlagAction])
}
```

[image]

**The image , i am using**

[image]

Comment: check your image size or where you get the image from assets or else

Comment: Dimension : 32*32

Comment: reduce the size and check once

Comment: Hi friend, i try it all the possible way to decrease Dimension of the image. same issues happend.

Comment: can u update the code

Comment: see this for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502901/is-there-a-recommended-image-size-for-uicontextualaction-icons

Comment: another ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578490/not-displaying-the-title-in-swipe-actions-for-uitableview-swift-4/50578710#50578710

Comment: try to set different image

Comment: Yes,i try it with another image

Comment: Can you please add that image to your question, if possible ? I think the issue is with that image.

Answer (score 0):

**we can take size 30 by 30 , is the standard size , we can take more than 30 pixel , depending on the size of the screen.**

> Here is the image that is support

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `UIContextualAction` only accepts **template image**, which use different transparent degree to define the image's shape and color.

Answer (score 0):

hi it is worked fine for me ,

That image size will auto adjust according to pixel of the image.

```
  private func searchBarCode(forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    
    let context = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "") { (action, swipeButtonView, completion) in
        completion(true)
    }
    context.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    context.image = UIImage(named: "document")
    
    return context
    }
```

[Click here to see table view edit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83RU8.png)